# Eloqua datapull using SQL

Tags: sql, rest, join, postman, eloqua

I need some information on accessing eloqua data using REST API( via Postman ), so to fetch eloqua DB data.

once after I fetch data using postman , I may need to query cdo tables  / contact table via sql query.
so postman needs to be connected to Apache drell or MySQL to perform SQL operations.

which performs the best between Apache drell & MySQL ! - it's pros and cons!

Comment: The solution would be similar to what I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311143/2685443). Drill can query CSVs directly, and importing CSVs into MySQL is well documented. Fetching the metadata or prototyping through postman is fine, but for the actual bulk extract is not recommended.